# Configuring SSL (https) for ws2007FederationHttpBinding Endpoint 404 No Endpoint found

Tags: wcf, ssl, https, wif, ws-federation

Another WIF related problem - can anyone point me in the direction of how to configure https in wcf for a ws2007FederationHttpBinding endpoint. I have the certificates and bindings all set-up in IIS, but whenever I try to connect to the endpoint I get a 404 error. My binding looks like this

```
<bindings>
    <ws2007FederationHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BindingConfigName">
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
                    <message establishSecurityContext="false">
              <issuerMetadata address="https://identity.localhost/issue/wstrust/mex" />
              <claimTypeRequirements>
                <add claimType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name" isOptional="true" />
                <add claimType="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role" isOptional="true" />
              </claimTypeRequirements>
            </message>
          </security>
        </binding>
    </ws2007FederationHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Endpoint Looks Like

```
<endpoint address="https://services.localhost/MyService.svc" binding="ws2007FederationHttpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="BindingConfigName"
      bindingNamespace="MyNamespace"
      contract="IServiceContract">
</endpoint>
```

Really struggling to see what to do.

Matt

Comment: I think the config above was fine - I had another endpoint configured in my web.config that was overriding this endpoint config I think!